# Screen is turned upside down

Tags: android, orientation, flip

I am testing/debugging an Android app and even though i have set

```
configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

and used

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

the screen turns upside down. This seems to appear on WXGA 4.0, 4.1, 4.2. Is it something related to the API, emulator or something else? I am asking this question because I didn't find anything official and clear.
Thank you.

PS: as a solution, in case there's an API problem, should i check it's version and rotate the screen or is there something better?

Comment: Thank you guys for the editing & formating :D

Answer (score 4):

HI I am using this for landscape

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main"  android:configChanges="orientation" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main"  android:configChanges="orientation" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

for portrait and its wrking for me android 4.1 simulator